# Tool tips confusing on up spinner and down spinner

Tags: feature-request, voting, usability

There is a general UI paradigm at SO:

```
up pointing triangle, clicking spins the number UP  

    N      an integer  

down pointing triangle, clicking spins the number DOWN
```

The respective tool tips are:

> **up:** This question is useful and clear (click again to undo)
>
> **down:** This question is unclear or not useful (click again to undo)

I'm new, so I'm guessing the wording ought to read something like this:

> **up:**  This question is useful and clear (click to increase the vote count, a second click subtracts one vote)  <== *clumsy wording, see alternative below* {gl}
>
> **up:**  This question is useful and clear (click to increase the vote count, click again to decrease)
>
> **down:** This question is unclear or not useful (click to decrease the vote count; costs one reputation point per click)

(my suggested wording is clumsy but at the same time it's clearer than "click again to undo" ~~ I say this because a tool tip needs to be helpful and instill confidence in the end user)

edit: ?? does down voting actually cost a reputation point?  {gl}

Comment: "a second click subtracts one vote", how about the third? The current text perhaps not the perfect one suggested the essence of 'toggling'.

Comment: @ o.k.w. as I stated, my wording is clumsy.  imo, the essence of toggling is insufficient.  ideally, a tool tip should be clear and if possible concise ...

Comment: Yes, downvoting does cost you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 4):

I understand what you're saying, but in the context of a browser a pointer cursor implies a clickable action and leads to the assumption that you're going to click it.  From this perspective the wording is logical.

Plus, I think the majority of people are getting it.  There seems to be a fair amount of voting happening!  I don't think it's worth changing.