# Changing your vote does not feel intuitive

Tags: discussion, voting

Just recently I down-voted a answer because of a technical error. A few minutes later they stopped by and resolved the issue. Satisfied, I clicked the up-vote button and the down-vote was removed. Not only was it removed but another up-vote was applied to their answer.

Does anyone else feel that the UI should not behave in this matter?

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39175/tool-tips-confusing-on-up-spinner-and-down-spinner

Comment: @Gnoupi - That is so weird. Why would Firefox fail to catch that spelling error?

Comment: I see down-votes are thrown about freely on meta. Anyone care to give a reason?

Comment: As well as indicating an unclear question or not useful post, down-votes are used to indicate disagreement with propositions or proposed solutions to questions. It's a way of indicating to Jeff and the dev team whether something's worth implementing or not.

Comment: @Chaos - re the spelling - FF doesn't spell checks text *boxes* (as used for titles) by default, whereas it does check text *areas* (as used for the body of the question).

Comment: @ChrisF - Interesting, so the community dynamics of meta are quite different from SO.

Comment: @Chaos - indeed they are ;) Don't forget, meta is a replacement for User Voice where you did explicitly vote on whether you thought an idea was good or not or whether you wanted a feature implemented or not.

Comment: @Chaos Check out [these instructions](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2914/firefox_3_enable_spell_check_in_text_boxes_not_just_textarea_fields_/) to enable spell-checking in textboxes in Firefox.

Comment: @Jared - That's awesome, thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. It is clear to me that by clicking on "This question is useful and clear (click again to undo)", I am effectively giving an upvote to it.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the OP doesn't know that to revert a vote you click again where you clicked before?

Comment: I do know this, the discussion is on the intuitiveness of the functionality.